# database connected but Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to ask somthing , why i always receive

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/dbmsmef/public_html/appointment/system/content/itenary/inputprocess_Itenary.php:9) in /home/dbmsmef/public_html/appointment/system/content/itenary/inputprocess_Itenary.php on line 28

once i want to submit after full fill the form , but if i check in my database on phpMyadmin, the data already update but when i run by localhost the warning pop up. can i know the code to settle the error ? i really need help

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when there is some output, echo, whitespace before session_start(). Even error message caused by some other part of a script is considered as output and thus triggers the 'headers already sent' error.